# python selenium: how to visit a web page many times on the same page

Tags: python, selenium, testing

I'm using selenium with python to test my web server. Here is my test code:

```
i = 0
msg = 'abc'
while i < 10:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get("http://www.example.com")
    txt = driver.find_element_by_id('input-text')
    txt.clear()
    txt.send_keys(msg)
    btn = driver.find_element_by_id('input-search')
    btn.click()
    driver.quit()
    i += 1
```

The code works well except only one thing: it executes Chrome, do the test and close it for each time of loop. Obviously it's not necessary. What I need is simply to execute Chrome only one time and do many requests. I've tried as below but it doesn't work:

```
i = 0
msg = 'abc'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
while i < 10:
    driver.get("http://www.example.com")
    txt = driver.find_element_by_id('input-text')
    txt.clear()
    txt.send_keys(msg)
    btn = driver.find_element_by_id('input-search')
    btn.click()
    i += 1
driver.quit()
```

I think it's because in my test, there are two things:
1) fill `abc` in input-text;
2) click a button, submit the `abc` and open a new web page.

On the new page, there is also an `input-text` and a button `input-search`, so it will fill the `abc` and click the button on the new page, which is not what I want.

Comment: Is there any error message or stack trace?

Comment: @Buaban   I just tested again and it doesn't block in fact. I've reedited my question.

Comment: Do you mean the line`driver.get("http://www.example.com")` doesn't work?

Comment: @Buaban   Yeah. I thought `driver.get` should visit this link but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Can you try this? `driver.get("http://www.example.com/?random="+uuid.uuid4())`. Please note that you need to import the `uuid` module by 'import uuid`

Comment: @Buaban  Now I get an error: `no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"input-text"}`. I think nothing changes. In fact, I use random messages to do the test. If the message can be processed, it will open the new page which contains another input-text and another button. Otherwise, an 404 page will be opened. So if it gets the 404, this error will be produced. If not, it will still stay on the new page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147321/discussion-between-buaban-and-yves).

Comment: What do you expect to happen?

Comment: after clicking on the button , use can use driver.back() or  driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)") . It will take you to the previous page

Comment: @santhoshkumar In fact it's not about what you said. Join the chat if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At `btn.click()`, it doesn't wait for page loaded because it is not a hyperlink and it doesn't submit a webform. So your script might be failed. You should fix it by waiting for some elements to determine if it should reload page or not. See code below.

```
try:
    driver.get('http://www.example.com')
    txt = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "input-text")))
    txt.clear()
    txt.send_keys(msg)
    btn = driver.find_element_by_id('input-search')
    btn.click() 
    countryDescriptionElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "country-description")))
    #print(driver.page_source.encode('utf-8')) 
except WebDriverException as ex:
    print("Enter: " + msg + ", Error: " + str(ex) + ", Found: " + driver.page_source)
```